# Python future install_aliases 'module' object has no attribute 'getoutput'

Tags: python-2.7, apache-beam

I'm facing an issue trying to install python apache beam version on a clean python 2.7.15 on virtualenv.

There's an import issue with [future (0.16)](http://python-future.org/) dependency trying to setup modules aliases

```
>>> from future import standard_library
>>> standard_library.install_aliases()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/leopold/.pyenv/versions/rastervision4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/future/standard_library/__init__.py", line 541, in install_aliases
obj = getattr(oldmod, oldobjname)
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getoutput'

I've tried on earlier versions of future package (0.12) and still the same problem.

Thanks!